# What does "Cookie: foo=bar" mean?

Tags: http, web, cookies

I see this code `Cookie: foo=bar` very often. What does it mean exactly? Is that some universal set for cookies?

Answer (score 1):

This is demonstrating the syntax of the Cookie header by using the common "foo" and "bar" example variable/value names.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

> The terms foobar (/ˈfuːbɑːr/), or foo and others are used as
>   placeholder names (also referred to as metasyntactic variables) in
>   computer programming or computer-related documentation.[1] They have
>   been used to name entities such as variables, functions, and commands
>   whose exact identity is unimportant and serve only to demonstrate a
>   concept.